# Evaluation or simplification of $\displaystyle{\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}}\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{A-\cos x-Bx}}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, power-series, elliptic-integrals

The period for an inverted pendulum on which some external forces act is expressed in terms of its initial angle, $\Phi_o\in[0º,70º]$ (higher angles are unstable), as
$$\mathcal{T}(\Phi_o)=2\sqrt 2\sqrt{\dfrac{\ell}{g}}\int_0^{\Phi_o}\dfrac{d\Phi}{\sqrt{(\cos\Phi_o-\cos\Phi)+\zeta(\Phi_o-\Phi)}},$$

where $g$ is gravity, and $\ell$ and $\zeta$ are pendulum-related constants.

In brief, we're interested in
$$\int_0^{\Phi_o}\dfrac{d\Phi}{\sqrt{A-\cos\Phi-B\Phi}}.$$

Is there any series expansion for this integral or any elliptical type function describing it maybe? Using Desmos to visualize the period in terms of the initial angle, looks like there shouldn't be any problem with convergence of this integral within the initial angle's interval and zeta's interval, $\zeta\in[0,2]$.

If it were too hard to find an expression in terms of $\Phi_o$, at least it'd want to try it for $\Phi_o=\frac{\pi}{4}$, which is the default inital value I use the most.

Comment: Perhaps you can make the substitution $A-\cos(x)-Bx=y\implies dx=f’_{a,b}(y)$ and expand $f_{a,b}(y)$ using [Kepler’s equation series solution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation#Inverse_problem)

Comment: What about expanding $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$?:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int\dfrac{d\Phi}{\sqrt{A-\cos\Phi-B\Phi}}&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt A}\int\dfrac{d\Phi}{\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{\cos\Phi-B\Phi}{A}\right)}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt A}\int\sum_{n\in\mathbf{N}_0}C_n\left(\dfrac{\cos\Phi-B\Phi}{A}\right)^n d\Phi\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt A}\sum_{n\in\mathbf{N}_0}C_n\int\left(\dfrac{\cos\Phi-B\Phi}{A}\right)^n d\Phi.
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: You could, but how would you integrate $(\cos(x)-bx)^n$ without another series expansion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\def\C{\operatorname C} \def\S{\operatorname S} \def\J{\operatorname J} $

$$\int_0^c\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a-\cos(x)-bx}}=\frac1{\sqrt b}\int_{-c-\frac\pi2}^{-\frac\pi2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x-\left(-\frac1b\right)\sin(x)+\frac\pi2+\frac ab}}$$

Substitute: $$x-\left(-\frac1b\right)\sin(x)\to x-\frac\pi2-\frac ab\implies dx\to f’_{-\frac1b}\left(x-\frac\pi2-\frac ab\right)dx$$

where $f_v(x)$ is the [Kepler equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KeplersEquation.html) Fourier series solution and $\J_n(x)$ is [Bessel J](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselJ.html)

$$f_v(x)=x+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\J_n(vn)}n\sin(nx)\\f’_v(x)=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}^\infty\J_n(vn)\cos(nx)$$

Therefore:

$$\int_0^c\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a-\cos(x)-bx}}=\int_{\frac{a-\cos(c)}b-c}^\frac{a-1}b\frac {dx}{\sqrt{bx}}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\J_n\left(-\frac nb\right)\int_{\frac{a-\cos(c)}b-c}^\frac{a-1}b\cos\left(n\left(x-\frac\pi2-\frac ab\right)\right)\frac{dx}{\sqrt{bx}}$$

The integral [requires](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5Bcos%28n+%28y-%CF%80%2F2-a%2Fb%29%291%2F%E2%88%9A%28y%29%2Cy%5D) [normalized Fresnel functions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5B%7BFresnelS%2CFresnelC%7D%2Cx%5D):

$$\boxed{\int_0^c\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a-\cos(x)-bx}}=\left.\left[2\sqrt\frac xb+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sqrt\frac{2\pi}{bn}\J_n\left(-\frac nb\right)\left(\cos\left(n\left(\frac ab+\frac\pi 2\right)\right)\C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2n}\pi x}\right)+ \sin\left(n\left(\frac ab+\frac\pi 2\right)\right)\S\left(\sqrt{\frac{2n}\pi x}\right)\right)\right]\right|_{\frac{a-\cos(c)}b-c}^\frac{a-1}b}$$

or via [unnormalized Fresnel integrals $\int_0^x e^{it^2}dt=\C(x)+i\S(x)$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral):

$$\boxed{\int_0^c\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a-\cos(x)-bx}}=\left.\left[2\sqrt\frac xb+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac4{\sqrt{bn}}\J_n\left(-\frac nb\right)\left(\cos\left(n\left(\frac ab+\frac\pi 2\right)\right)\C\left(\sqrt{nx}\right)+ \sin\left(n\left(\frac ab+\frac\pi 2\right)\right)\S\left(\sqrt{nx}\right)\right)\right]\right|_{\frac{a-\cos(c)}b-c}^\frac{a-1}b}$$

shown here:

[image]

Comment: Is there a problem here?

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a-\cos(x)-bx}}\ne \frac1{\sqrt b}\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x-\left(-\frac1b\right)\sin(x)+\frac\pi2+\frac ab}}$$

Comment: To all: if the indefinite integral is wanted, then it could be done